# PySImpleGUI -> How to play audio in the Background

Tags: python, pysimplegui, pydub

I'm using PySimpleGUI for creation of a simple program where a music should be played in the background of the GUI, but the problem is that Audio is played first and after that only the GUI appears, Is there any method to solve this Issue ?

Here I'm using **pydub** for playing audio since others may result in an error when converted to .exe

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from PySimpleGUI import *
st="W"
if st=="W":
    path_to_file="congratulation.mp3"
    song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path_to_file)
elif st=="F":
    path_to_file="fail.mp3"
    song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path_to_file)
layout=[[Text("You've "+st)],[Button("OK")]]
window=Window("Test",layout)
while True:
    play(song)
    e,v=window2.read()
    if e==None or e=="OK":
        exit()
```

Comment: Does any other modules for playing audio resolves this Issue ?

Comment: Can you run the player in a separate thread?

Comment: @RufusVS Used threading, got the same result as in the question : [

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to solve your problem would be to create a thread that plays the sound.

```
import threading as thread

# Your code

while True:
    thread.start_new_thread(play, (song, ))
    # The rest of your code
```

The above should work, if what you wanted to do was to play the sound in the background while the program kept going. This wouldn't allow you to stop the sound in the middle, however, and it could feasibly play several overlapping instances of the sound if the loop runs several times in quick succession.

Pydub has a closed issue regarding something similar: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/160

The answer there is a bit more comprehensive than what you asked for in your question, though.

Edited to add: I believe there are other, non-default players that does this or something similar by default, but if the sound is a simple, uplifting "ding" or a sad buzzer, more complex solutions could be superfluous.

Comment: Bro, but the sound played first and then only the GUI appeared :(

Answer (score 0):

Example code to play mp3, but only for non-stop play even after window closed, or next song played. Bugs or functions of pydub ignored here.

```py
import threading
from pathlib import Path

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import PySimpleGUI as sg


font = ('Courier New', 11)
sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Song file to play')],
    [sg.Input(enable_events=True, key='-SONG-'),
     sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("All MP3 Files", "*.mp3"),))],
    [sg.Button('Play'), sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window("Pydub MP3 Player", layout, finalize=True)
song = None
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == '-SONG-':
        path_to_file = values['-SONG-']
        if Path(path_to_file).is_file():
            try:
                song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path_to_file)
            except:
                pass
    elif event == 'Play':
        if song:
            threading.Thread(target=play, args=(song,), daemon=True).start()

window.close()
```

Comment: OMG... Bro,the song was repeating over and over and it was like running a Virus :)  At last I stopped the process. Actually ,I'm looking for something that plays the sound only once (The sound is just 5 seconds long), Is there any other Method for this?

Comment: Try to use other library to play, like VLC, refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Media_Player_VLC_Based.py